# htaccess RewriteRule to shorten the URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to find a `RewriteRule` that does this :

`mysite.net/jqMAS/` or `mysite.net/jqMAS` =>  `mysite.net/index.php?id=jqMAS`

I used such a `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?id=$1
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work (maybe *mysite.net/index.php* is itself redirected to *mysite.net/index.php?index.php*, etc. ?) : calling `mysite.net/jqMAS` produces a `500 Internal Server Error`.

**What `RewriteRule` should we use to do such URL shortening ?**

---

Here is what the `index.php` page (I didn't mention the headers) looks like :

```
  <body>
  Bonjour <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
  </body>
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` what doesn't work?

Comment: @Qix : calling mysite.net/jqMAS produces a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: @Basj What does apache error log says?

Comment: On Linux look at /var/logs/apache/error.log

Comment: @RahilWazir I don't have access to `error.log`. I have a shared 1&1 hosting. The only logs I have are : `access.log.38.7`  and `mail.log.38.7`   (38 is for the week number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 htaccess files:
Keep your htaccess file within application folder as:
Deny from all.

and paste following code to your htaccess file outside the application folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

It is working perfect for me.

Comment: Thanks! I still get a `500 Internal Server Error`... I don't know why. What about the 2 .htaccess files ? I only have one. Can you give some details about "Deny from all"? Do you speak about file permissions? What file permissions should I set for .htaccess and for index.php ? 644 ?

Comment: are you getting this error on localhost or on server link??

Comment: I don't know the reason. I solved by setting all files to permission 644 and finally used : 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`, `RewriteEngine On`, `RewriteBase /`, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]`, `</IfModule>`

Comment: How will this rule populate `$_GET['id']`?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following your .htaccess file, as it is the setup successfully used on my own website.

```
# Enable the rewriting engine.
RewriteEngine On

# Change requests for a shorter URL
# Requires one or more characters to follow the domain name to be redirected
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?id=$1             [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `RewriteCond` to stop rewriting for real files and directories:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if request is not for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```